# I can't delete pure text using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have error message on the page that I want to delete using Jquery while the error is getting fixed.

I can delete all the `b` tags but I have some elements that are only pure text and I can't figure it out.

Any help, will be appreciate

This is the html:

```
<body class = "body.home.page.page-id-273">
<br>
<b>Notice</b>
":  Undefined variable: output in "
<b>/var/www/vhost/adelapereira.com/home/html/wp-content/themes/optimizePressTheme/lib/assets/default.php</b>
</b>
" on line "
 <b>2589</b>
 <br>
 ...
```

And this is the Jquery I delete all the text inside the b tags, but not the pure text:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("b, b:nth-child(2), b:nth-child(3), b:nth-child(4)").css( "display", "none" );
}); 
</script>
```

Many thanks

Comment: This error is thrown by php and not JavaScript

Comment: You can target all the `<b>` elements with just `$('b')`, no need for the `nth-child` stuff. Also it would help to see the HTML for the complete page you're working with. If what you posted above is it, then just delete the HTML within the `<body>` element

Comment: Many thanks, there could be  other b tags and there are a complete page, is this one: http://adelapereira.com/

Comment: Why deleting the error msg like that? You should use the display_errors = false property inside the php configuration. What's the context? Edit: or, you know, fix the actual error.

Comment: Many thanks, I did, but it didn't work, so while I fix the error, I am trying to delete by this way.

Comment: You might try wrapping your error message in a container, then either, use display: none or using some other method to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you have no other text nodes as body childs:

```js
$('b:eq(0), b:eq(1)').remove();
var contents = $('body').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Notice</b>
":  Undefined variable: output in "
<b>/var/www/vhost/adelapereira.com/home/html/wp-content/themes/optimizePressTheme/lib/assets/default.php</b>
```

Comment: it worked, just adding b:eq(2): $('b:eq(0), b:eq(1)').remove();   many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('b').hide();
 }); 
</script>
```

**EDIT**

**- Change your html to this:**

```
<body class = "body.home.page.page-id-273">
<div class="hide_this">
<br>
<b>Notice</b>
":  Undefined variable: output in "
<b>/var/www/vhost/adelapereira.com/home/html/wp-content/themes/optimizePressTheme/lib/assets/default.php</b>
</b>
" on line "
 <b>2589</b>
 <br>
</div>
...
```

-
    In your jQuery

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.content').after('<div class="hide_this">');
     $('.fancybox-wrap').before('</div>');
     $('.hide_this').hide();
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks luissimo, that works for b tag, but I still can't hide the no tags elements, the pure text

Comment: Thanks, yep, I am sure that with that, it will work, but the problem is now that I  still don't know how to wrap it into <div class="hide_this">

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. I tried to other solutions wrapping the elements but nothing. @skobaljic gives a working solution. best